# Contact form 7, как создать обработчик?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Как добавить свой php-обработчик для contact form 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

В плагине есть хук `wpcf7_before_send_mail`, можно использовать его.

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 
    // обработка здесь... 
}; 

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail' );
```

Comment: данную тему создал на основе этой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722788/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B
Не затруднит ли подсказать в теме по приведённой ссылке?

Comment: я этот вопрос видел, но ничего сказать не могу